# Range Slider not working properly in Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I want to be able to get range slider and a selector in my graph, I have followed the example in the documentation, but I’m getting the following error:

1.- The selector dates, are still using ‘backwards’, as opposed to ‘todate’, which is a bit weird, perhaps is the fact that I'm not understanding this 100%, but I would like to get 6 and 12 months from today, is there a way to use a forward from the earliest date period?

https://jsfiddle.net/jt1o26bd/

```
var Deals = {
                      x: {{ deals_plot.lic_deals_date|safe }},
                      y: {{ deals_plot.lic_deals_licenses }},
                      name: 'Active Licenses',
                      type: 'bar',
                      marker: {
                                color: 'rgb(0,131,117)',

                              }
                    };
       var Leads = {
                      x: {{ deals_plot.lic_leads_date|safe }},
                      y: {{ deals_plot.lic_leads_licenses }},
                      name: 'Potential Licenses',
                      type: 'bar',
                      marker: {
                                color: 'rgb(160,220,210)',

                              }
                    };

       var data = [Deals,Leads];

       var layout = {
                title: 'Software Licenses Term',
                barmode: 'stack',
                xaxis: {
                       autorange: true,
                       rangeselector: {buttons: [
                                                     {step: 'all'},
                                                    {
                                                      count: 1,
                                                      label: 'YTD',
                                                      step: 'year',
                                                      stepmode: 'todate'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                      count: 6,
                                                      label: '6m',
                                                      step: 'month',
                                                      stepmode: 'todate'
                                                    }
                                                    ]},
                       rangeslider: { },
                       type: 'date',
                        tickfont:{
                           size: 14
                            },
                        },
                yaxis: {
                      tickfont:{
                                size: 14
                            }
                     }

        };
```

Could anyone let me know what is going on?

Comment: I am a bit confused by what you're asking – do you mean that you want to go forward in time instead of backward in time you click the rangeselector buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You might already understand the difference between `backward` and `todate` but backward will go back by exactly the `count` number of `steps`, and todate will go back by whatever amount of time is needed to round to the first count number of steps.

For example, the expected behavior of the `YTD` button constructed with arguments `count: 1, step: 'y', stepmode: 'todate'` will be to go back to Jan 1 of from the year at the end of your current daterange. Your jsfiddle does indeed do this:

[image]

If you were to construct your YTD button with `stepmode: 'backward'`, then when you click on the button, the daterange would instead move back to Nov 2022.

Since you asked about buttons going forward in time instead of backward, this feature does not currently exist in plotly according to this [forum post](https://community.plotly.com/t/rangeselector-stepmode-forward/14112/2), but @scoutlt appears to have solved the problem for themselves by modifying their local version of plotly.js - however their solution is no longer up to date with the latest version of the library.

If you go into `plotly.js/src/components/rangeselector/get_update_object.js` you can see that there is a function called `getXRange` where the `backward` and `todate` are defined:

```
function getXRange(axisLayout, buttonLayout) {
    var currentRange = axisLayout.range;
    var base = new Date(axisLayout.r2l(currentRange[1]));
    var step = buttonLayout.step;

    var utcStep = d3Time['utc' + titleCase(step)];

    var count = buttonLayout.count;
    var range0;

    switch(buttonLayout.stepmode) {
        case 'backward':
            range0 = axisLayout.l2r(+utcStep.offset(base, -count));
            break;

        case 'todate':
            var base2 = utcStep.offset(base, -count);

            range0 = axisLayout.l2r(+utcStep.ceil(base2));
            break;
    }

    var range1 = currentRange[1];

    return [range0, range1];
}
```

Personally, I think the best solution would be to define another case called `forward` which does the opposite of backward:

```
switch(buttonLayout.stepmode) {
        case 'backward':
            range0 = axisLayout.l2r(+utcStep.offset(base, -count));
            break;

        case 'forward':
            range0 = axisLayout.l2r(+utcStep.offset(base, count));
            break;

        case 'todate':
            var base2 = utcStep.offset(base, -count);

            range0 = axisLayout.l2r(+utcStep.ceil(base2));
            break;
    }
```

However, I haven't worked much with the plotly.js repo, and there is the possibility that this will cause a breaking change (and might break one or more of the unit tests, for example).

If that is the case, you can do something similar to what @scoutlt did in the forum post, and change the definition of backward to mean forward (personally i think this is a pretty hacky approach, so I would only do this if defining forward doesn't work, and you want your buttons to ONLY go forward). That would look something like:

```
switch(buttonLayout.stepmode) {
        case 'backward':
            range0 = axisLayout.l2r(+utcStep.offset(base, count));
            break;

        case 'todate':
            var base2 = utcStep.offset(base, -count);

            range0 = axisLayout.l2r(+utcStep.ceil(base2));
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Derek, thank you very much, I'm mainly a Django guy, building knowledge in Jquery/Javascript, where do I have to add the switch function, and then do I have to call the function on document load?

Comment: @FranciscoColina you have to modify the `getXRange` function in the source `plotly.js/src/components/rangeselector/get_update_object.js` file

Comment: Thanks, now I get what you are saying, however, I'm getting plotly via CDN <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>, obviously, this is easier from a django perspective, but then I don't think that I can modify the contains of plotly.js

Comment: @FranciscoColina i have to admit i'm not too familiar with django, but if you can't modify plotly.js then unfortunately you are probably stuck with a range slider that only goes backwards. if I have time, i might consider submitting a PR to the plotly team and see if they'll allow this modification to their getXRange function in plotly.js but even if it were approved, i don't think this change would be reflected until the next plotly.js update is released